# how to count consecutive in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list `decider = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]`. In this list, I want to print +150 in front of 1 and -150 in front of 0. But the condition is that, you can only put +150 or -150 up to 4 consecutive times, after that you have to put 0 in the list if still, you are getting 0 or 1.
Expected Output:

```
decider result
1        150
1        150
1        150
1        150
1         0
0       -150
0       -150
0       -150
1        150
1        150
1        150
0       -150 
0       -150
0       -150
0       -150
```

My Approach:

```
test = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
Charge_counter = 0
Discharge_counter = 0
charge = []
discharge = []
for i in test:
    if i ==1:
        Charge_counter += 1
        if Charge_counter <=4:
            charge.append(150)
        else:
            charge.append(0)
    else:
        Discharge_counter += 1
        if Discharge_counter <= 4:
            discharge.append(-150)
        else:
            discharge.append(0)
print(charge)
print(discharge)
```

Comment: what you have coded so far ?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my code there. Now I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems with your code

- You are not resetting `Charge_counter` and `Discharge_counter`
- Unnecessary to use 2 lists

### Solution

```py
test = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
charge = 0
discharge = 0
ans_charged = []
ans_discharged = []

for i in test:
    if i == 1 and charge < 4:
        ans_charged.append(150)
        ans_discharged.append(0)
        charge +=1
        discharge = 0 
    elif i == 1:
        ans_charged.append(0)
        ans_discharged.append(0)
        discharge = 0 
    elif i == 0 and discharge < 4:
        ans_discharged.append(-150)
        ans_charged.append(0)
        discharge += 1
        charge = 0
    elif i == 0:
        ans_discharged.append(0)
        ans_charged.append(0)
        charge = 0 
print(ans_charged)
print(ans_discharged)
```

### Output

```sh
[150, 150, 150, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -150, -150, -150, -150, 0, 0, 0, 0, -150, -150, -150, -150]
```

Comment: yeah that's the answer. Thanks. But I want to use two lists because they have differents uses further

Comment: but the ans_charged and ans_discharged lists don't have the same number of elements as in test list.

Comment: the answer should be like: answer_charged =[150,150,150,150,0,0,0,0,0,0,150,150,150,0,0,0,0] and answer_discharged= [0,0,0,0,0,-150,-150,-150,-150,0,0,0,0,-150,-150,-150,-150]

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use `itertools` then you could do:

```
import itertools
decider = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
temp = [150 if i==1 else -150 for i in decider]
runs = [list(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(temp)]
print(runs)  # [[150, 150, 150, 150, 150], [-150, -150, -150], [150, 150, 150], [-150, -150, -150, -150]]
runs = [i[:4]+[0]*(len(i)-4) for i in runs]
print(runs)  # [[150, 150, 150, 150, 0], [-150, -150, -150], [150, 150, 150], [-150, -150, -150, -150]]
result = list(itertools.chain(*runs))
print(result)  # [150, 150, 150, 150, 0, -150, -150, -150, 150, 150, 150, -150, -150, -150, -150]
```

Explanation: I first change `1` to `150` and everything else to `-150`, then I find consecutive runs of 150 and -150 (note that `itertools.groupby` work this way as opposed to SQL `GROUP BY`), then I for every sublist get 4 first elements and concat it with (original length - 4) zeros. Note that in Python it is legal to multiply `list` by negative number (this result in empty `list`) so I do not have to implement special case for short lists. Finally I flatten - turn `list` of `list`s into flat `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:
NO need of 2 lists.
Need to reset the values of charge_counter = 0 and discharge_counter = 0

```
test = [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
charge_counter = 0
discharge_counter = 0
charge = []
for i in test:
    if i ==1 and charge_counter <4:
        charge.append(150)
        charge_counter += 1
        discharge_counter = 0
    elif i ==0 and discharge_counter <4:  
        charge.append(-150)
        discharge_counter += 1
        charge_counter = 0
    else:
        charge.append(i)
print(charge)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Discharge_counter to 0 in "if i == 1" condition, also you need to set Charge_counter to 0 in "else" condition.